ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' in docker while composing
i am trying to run my application on docker container while composing and after container is created i get this error and i trying to resolve this error but couldnot succeed, please help me understand the problem and suggest the solution to it.
web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web-1  |   File "/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
web-1  |     from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
web-1  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
web-1 exited with code 1

my dockerfile is
FROM python:3.12.3
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app


# Install Python dependencies, including Flask
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

docker compose file 
ersion: '3'
services:

  web:
    build: .
    command: python -u app.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: test_mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=Student_db
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

requirements.txt
    pymongo

Flask == 2.2.2

please let me know the solution.

"Flask and python is installed globally" is completely irrelevant. Also instead of pip list, can you please share your requirements.txt file and your docker compose file and also how you run your containers.

You don't seem to have included your Dockerfile's CMD line; can you make sure that's included as well?

@Bck `pymongo
Flask == 2.2.2this is the requirements.txt docker-compose.zml ersion: '3'
services:
web:
build: .
command: python -u app.py
ports:
- "5000:5000"
volumes:
- .:/app
links:
- db
db:
image: mongo:latest
hostname: test_mongodb
environment:
- MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=Student_db
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
ports:
- 27017:27017`
i just run this command "docker-compose up --build"

flask should be all lower case in the requirements.

@TimRoberts i tried this but still the error occurs

You're sure you have pip installed?  Does the docker log show any errors?
